# Why would ssh fail to expand %h variable in .ssh/config?

Tags: ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-6

Why would ssh fail to expand %h from .ssh/config?
This used to work and still works except on a RHEL box.
Looking for what the origin of this could be. Is there a setting somewhere that tells ssh to not expand %h?

I have something like this in my .ssh/config:

```
Host *.foo
  HostName %h.mydomain.com
```

On the RHEL box where this doesn't work, I get this:

```
$ ssh -vvvv bar.foo
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/zsimic/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *.foo
debug1: Applying options for *.foo
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
ssh: Could not resolve hostname %h.mydomain.com: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using OpenSSH 5.3; `%h` was only [introduced in OpenSSH **5.6**](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.6):

```
Changes since OpenSSH 5.5
=========================

 * Expand %h to the hostname in ssh_config Hostname options. While this
   sounds useless, it is actually handy for working with unqualified
   hostnames:

     Host *.*
        Hostname %h
     Host *
        Hostname %h.example.org
```

Answer (score 2):

`man ssh_config` does not mention that `%h` will be expanded in `HostName` clause. I'm using `openssh5.9p1`

edit: *it did and I missed it*

If setting up some proxy server ( a local-only one will do ) won't bother you, maybe some workaround with `ProxyCommand` is possible.

Or, you can enumerate a few hostnames in `.ssh/config` .

Comment: It used to work, and just stopped working on RHEL 6.1 with a recent update... I thought %h would be expanded everywhere, are you saying it's a gray area in the spec?

Comment: MAN on my machine did mention `%h` and I missed it. You may want to revoke the upvote. Equally confused now.